# spark json parsing issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

not sure why spark is leaving out last three columns in my Json when I try to query or print schema.

```
       val stringTest =
      """{
                               "total_count": 123,
                               "page_size": 20,
                               "another_id": "gdbfdbfdbd",
                               "sen": [{
                                "id": 123,
                                "ses_id": 12424343,
                                "columns": {
                                    "blah": "blah",
                                    "count": 1234
                                },
                                "class": {},
                                "class_timestamps": {},
                                "sentence": "spark is good"
                               }]
                            }
                             """
    val result1 = List(stringTest)
    val githubRdd1=spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(result1)
    val gitHubDF1=spark.read.json(githubRdd1)
    gitHubDF1.show()
    gitHubDF1.printSchema()
```

why is it missing out class,class_timestamps,senstense from Json string ?

Print schema value from spark

```
root
 |-- another_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- page_size: long (nullable = true)
 |-- sen: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- columns: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- blah: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sentence: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ses_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- total_count: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Because those fields don’t have value. If you have another row with all values populated then schema will be derived correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because those fields class,class_timestamps,senstense are empty. It can't derive schema without knowing the data inside. So to derive sample schema you need to provide at least one fully populated json row.

```
    val stringTest1 =      """{
                               "total_count": 123,
                               "page_size": 20,
                               "another_id": "gdbfdbfdbd",
                               "sen": [{
                                "id": 123,
                                "ses_id": 12424343,
                                "columns": {
                                    "blah": "blah",
                                    "count": 1234
                                },
                                "class": {"name":"className"},
                                "class_timestamps": {"timestamp1" : 1234},
                                "sentence": "spark is good"
                               }]
                            }
                             """
    val stringTest =
      """{
                               "total_count": 123,
                               "page_size": 20,
                               "another_id": "gdbfdbfdbd",
                               "sen": [{
                                "id": 123,
                                "ses_id": 12424343,
                                "columns": {
                                    "blah": "blah",
                                    "count": 1234
                                },
                                "class": {},
                                "class_timestamps": {},
                                "sentence": "spark is good"
                               }]
                            }
                             """
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.read.json(Seq(stringTest,stringTest1).toDS)
    df.printSchema()
```

Schema -

```
root
 |-- another_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- page_size: long (nullable = true)
 |-- sen: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- class: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- class_timestamps: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- timestamp1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- columns: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- blah: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sentence: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ses_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- total_count: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: is there a way I can pass default some value? I have to explicitly pass schema which is something I don't want because source json schema keep changing, choices I have is to create dynamic sql on the fly based on data frame schema

Comment: looks like I have to create an empty data frame with schema what I am expecting and union all both the data frames.

Comment: You should provide schema otherwise you will face runtime error when a column is accessed but not present

Comment: If you have schema available will data column then you can parse data dynamically

Comment: I am trying to write sql query dynamically based on json schema

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use spark internal Json library. It become very complex to handle schema of nested json. Instead read it as String and parse that Json String to Json object using below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20190722</version>
</dependency>
```

for sbt it's

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json" % "json" % "20190722"
```

and use below libraries to convert Json:

```
val jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr)
val jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr)
```

There are several "get" methods in it to fetch specific object/string/int/timestamp/array etc.